# C# DateTime Conversion from yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss to dd MMM yyyy

Tags: c#

How to convert "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss" into "dd MMM yyyy" format? For Instance, i want to convert 2013-04-16 05:30:05 into 16 April 2013. What is the correct method to achieve this?

Comment: Both of those are text representations, do you have a `DateTime` object or do you have a string in the `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss` format?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, a `DateTime` has no format. But if you've already a string that represents a `DateTime` with the format `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss` and you want to convert it to a string-date with format `dd MMM yyyy` you need to parse it to `DateTime` first.

Therefore use `DateTime.ParseExact`:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("2013-04-16 05:30:05", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", null);
```

Now you can use `DateTime.ToString`:

```
string result = dt.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
```

Note that you need to   pass a different `CultureInfo` object to `ParseExact`/`ToString` if you want to parse with another `DateTimeFormat` than your current (f.e. force english month names instead of german: `dt.ToString("dd MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`).

Answer (score 11):

First [`ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) then do `ToString` (I assume that you have string object, if you have DateTime object, skip first line)

```
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(yourDateString, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var yourNewString = dateTime.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
```

Note that representation of `DateTime` you see in debugger is dependant on your current culture.

Answer (score 3):

As others mentioned, a DateTime has no format. To parse a string literal to a Date you need to call DateTime.Parse (if the string is in a culture-specific format) or [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you need to pass a format string.

The format can be a custom format like `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` or one of the [standard format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), eg. `s` for `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss`.

`2013-04-16 05:30:05` it *not* in one of the standard formats, so you have to parse by passing a custom format string:

```
    var dt = DateTime.ParseExact("2013-04-16 05:30:05", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", null);
```

On the other hand, `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss` is the `s` standard format so you can just write:

```
    var dt = DateTime.ParseExact("2013-04-16T05:30:05", "s", null);
```