# Convert string in form of "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss" to DateTime object in c#

Tags: asp.net-web-api, c#-4.0

I Want to convert string in form of "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss" to DateTime object. Is there is any way to convert it.

Comment: you can' t convert a template string to datetime. You have to post a string with the real time.

Comment: I [searched Google for the title of your question](https://www.google.com/search?q=Convert+string+in+form+of+%22yyyy-MM-ddTHH%3Amm%3Ass%22+to+DateTime+object+in+c%23) and [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20090297/1202807) was the first result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# DateTime Conversion from yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss to dd MMM yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20090297/c-sharp-datetime-conversion-from-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmss-to-dd-mmm-yyyy)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact("2021-12-18T05:30:05", "s", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```